# keep the modal open after form submit in codeigniter and trying a bit of ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

so this is my controller:

**User_Authentication_Controller:**

```
public function login_user(){
   $username = $this->input->post('txt_login_username');
   $password = md5($this->input->post('txt_login_password'));

   $result=$this->LogIn_Model->login($username,$password);
   redirect('Pages_Controller/homepage');
}
```

**LogIn_Model:**

```
public function LogIn($username,$password){
   $data = array(
   'username' => $username,
   'password' => $password
   );

   $query = $this->db->get_where('user_account',$data);
           return $query->result_array();   
}
```

**LOGIN MODAL:**

```
<section id="login_modal" class="modal fade" >
 <div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header"></div>
    <div class="modal-body" id="forms">
     <div class="loginmodal-container">
      <h1>Login to Your Account</h1><br>
       <form class="form-horizontal" id="form_login" action="" method="POST">   
        <div class='error_msg'></div>
         <input autofocus="autofocus" type="text" id="txt_login_username" name="txt_login_username" class="form-control" />
        <input type="password" id="txt_login_password" name="txt_login_password" class="form-control" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="btnLogin">Login</button>    
        <a href="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/Pages_Controller/show_forgotpassword">Forgot Password?</a>                   
     </div>     
  </form>               
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
                <center><button type = "submit" id="login_user" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal" >CLOSE</button></center>
        </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**VIEW:**

```
    <a href="#" onclick="$('#login_modal').modal({'backdrop': 'static'});" id="login">Login</a>
```

**AJAX:**

```
  $(function(){
    $('#login_user').submit(function(event){

        var user = $('#txt_login_username').val();
        var pass = $('#txt_login_password').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'User_Authentication_Controller/login_user',
        data: {
        'user': user,
        'pass': pass
        },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(results){
            if(user != user){
                $('.error_msg').html('error msg');
                      return false;
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

ALL I WANT IS IF THERE IS AN ERROR! THE  will work and the modal will not close! how will I do that with CI? Is there any possible way that just put the LogIn_Model->login(); in AJAX? please help! I need this thing badly! And in addition I want that what the user inputs and if he got it wrong when he submitted the username will still be at the textbox! how will I do that also? THank you so much for help!

Comment: Can you tell us what issue you are facing

Comment: I just want the modal to stay still after an error with Codeigniter, is this possible?

Comment: Yes of course but its not codeigniter's work,you need to do it using javascript by `return false`

Comment: how? can i get some code? i am really not into jscript or ajax jquery thing, im using php and CI but since modal not closing will only work on script that is why im asking this question

Comment: it's just like @Zeeshan said, it got nothing to do with CI, all you got to know is how you open/close the modal programatically. Assuming you probably using bootstrap as your css framework. Maybe this link would help to fix your problem. http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#js-programmatic-api